# Ruby on Rails Money gem: create money from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm quite new to Rails and this is the first time I'm using the money git. I inserted the following code into my model, as stated in the money gem wiki:

```
composed_of :cash,
:class_name => "Money",
:mapping => [%w(amount cents), %w(currency currency_as_string)],
:constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency ||     Money.default_currency) },
:converter => Proc.new { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_money) ? value.to_money :     raise(ArgumentError, "Can't convert #{value.class} to Money") }
```

In my database I have two fields: amount (integer) and currency (string)

I also have a form, were users can enter a certain cash-amount:

```
<%= f.number_field :amount %>
```

The problem here is that users fill in their amount like 1,50 instead of 150 cents. What is the best way to convert the user input of 1,50 to 150 before inserting this into the database?

Regards,
Gerwin

Answer (score 0):

Replace comma with dot, parse as float and multiply by 100.

```
("1,50".gsub(',', '.').to_f * 100).to_i
# => 150
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options are available.

In all cases you will need to be aware of the currency that the value is being entered in **if** it is entered in a format other than the default currency defined in `Money.default_currency`.

1) Use the new composed_of accessor `#cash`.

```
<%= f.number_field :cash %>
```

note: the f.number_field method generates a number spinner not a text field.

2) Overload the definition of `#amount`. Please note, that i think this method negates the need for composed_of macro.

```
def amount
  cents = read_attribute(:amount) || 0
  currency = read_attribute(:currency_as_string) || Money.default_currency
  Money.new(cents, currency)
end

def amount=(value)
  cash = Money.from_string(value)
  write_attribute(:amount, cash.cents)
end
```

Take a look at the class methods Money.from_* in the [documentation](http://money.rubyforge.org), specifically, take a look a the method `Money.from_string` [[link]](http://money.rubyforge.org/Money.html#from_string-class_method).